# Geonode : Rotate each face on their own axis and limit slope

Tags: geometry-nodes

I need to turn the faces of a mesh to limit the slope.

1. I can't get the faces to rotate in the direction of their normals. (with an independent origin for each face)
2. Is it possible to assign a maximum and minimum slope to a mesh?

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you rephrase ? You're already rotating each face along its normal ?
"in the direction of its normal" doesn't really makes sense, as by definition a face is already rotated towards its normal. I'm not sure what you meant by that

Comment: Hi and sorry for my English,

I'd like to limit the maximum slope of a mesh.
To do this, I'd like to rotate each face so that its slope is limited by a maximum and a minimum.

Currently, I can't rotate the faces as if each face had its own origin in the object's tilt axis (to limit the tilt).

Comment: Ok, so that axis is a tangent. You need to generate a tangent space for your mesh because that axis doesn't exist (yet). Higgsas has nodes for this (https://blenderartists.org/t/higgsas-geometry-nodes-groups-blender-3-3-3-4-3-5-3-6/1351737), but you can do something simpler in your case. I'll post an answer in a jiffy

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't know! I will look at this and continue my research while waiting for your response. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about limiting the slope, it depends whether you want to limit the slope of existing faces (even those which are already vertical or almost vertical) or if you want to limit *the rotation applied to those faces*.

For now here is a simple way to rotate faces along their tangent axis. The tangent is naively derived from the cross-product of their normal and the Z axis (in object space). This means the behaviour could become unpredictable for faces that are nearly flat (because the normal and the Z axis are the same).

[image]

(You don't have to capture the position because the topology doesn't change)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, you have solved my problem!

Yes, I can imagine that the behaviour of the faces can give an unpredictable result when we change the slopes of the mesh,
Currently I have a minimum slope and a maximum slope, the goal of this geometry node is to change the range of all slopes of the mesh to apply a max/min slope.

Thanks again ;)